# Repeat fields while initializing const struct

Tags: c

Sorry for possible duplicate. I don't know how to google it.

Is it allowed to repeat fields in initializer list of const struct?

Examples:

```
const struct first _first = {
    .value = 1,
    .value = 2, /* same field again */
};

const struct second _second = {
    .first = _first,
    .first.value = 3, /* and again */
};
```

Second case is more important of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is allowed, with later initializers overriding any that came before.

This is specified in section 6.7.9p19 of the C standard:

> The  initialization  shall  occur  in  initializer  list  order,  each
>   initializer  provided  for  a particular subobject overriding any
>   previously listed initializer for the same subobject; <sup>151)</sup> all
>   subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized
>   implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.
>
> 151) Any initializer for the subobject which is overridden and so not
>   used to initialize that subobject might not be evaluated at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot...  I knew it works in GCC but wanted to be sure this behavior is standard.